# control.refresh give me a cross thread exception despite invoke method

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to animate the background image of a button in a windows form simulating a spinning wheel (something more elegant than a spinning mouse pointer).
I'm doing this in a second thread that run a loop that animate the button background image rotation (the first thread is the main thread where the form is created).

here is the class, the second thread run the spin() method:

```
Public Class spinningWhell
    Private Delegate Sub DelRefreshButton()
    Public rotate As Boolean
    Private TargetButton As Button
    Private ButtonForm As Windows.Forms.Form
    Private myImage As Image

    Public Sub New(ByRef PassedButton As Button)
        TargetButton = PassedButton
        ButtonForm = PassedButton.Parent
        myImage = TargetButton.BackgroundImage.Clone
    End Sub

    Public Sub spin()
        Do While rotate
            myImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)
            Thread.Sleep(100)
            refreshButton()
        Loop
    End Sub
    Private Sub refreshButton()
        If ButtonForm.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim del As New DelRefreshButton(AddressOf refreshButton)
            ButtonForm.Invoke(del)
        End If
        TargetButton.BackgroundImage = myImage
        ButtonForm.Refresh()

        'Form1.Button1.Refresh()
        'TargetButton.Refresh()
        'Application.OpenForms.Item(TargetButton.Parent.Name).Refresh()
        'Form1.Button1.Refresh()
    End Sub

End Class
```

despite using the Invoke method, buttonform.refresh() give me a cross thead exception.
I have tried to invoke the button or the form (the commented line after ButtonForm.refresh)
but the only one working is Form1.button1.refresh() where Form1 and Button1 are the name of the form and the button.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two lines that actually update the GUI need to be in an **ELSE** block so they are only executed once the method is actually being executed on the main UI thread:

Change:

```
Private Sub refreshButton()
    If ButtonForm.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim del As New DelRefreshButton(AddressOf refreshButton)
        ButtonForm.Invoke(del)
    End If
    TargetButton.BackgroundImage = myImage
    ButtonForm.Refresh()
End Sub
```

To:

```
Private Sub refreshButton()
    If ButtonForm.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim del As New DelRefreshButton(AddressOf refreshButton)
        ButtonForm.Invoke(del)
    Else
        TargetButton.BackgroundImage = myImage
        ButtonForm.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: oh sorry, what a stupid error. but why the cross thread exception occour only with ButtonForm.refresh() and not with the background image change? if I comment the refresh line there is no exception but the GUI don't update

Comment: The controls aren't very consistent in this respect.  Some will cause errors while others will not.  This is also the case for when you read values.  I don't know why this is, though.  The only way to be sure is to Invoke() everything.  =\